# Disable Computer from booting into gnome

Tags: gnome, server, boot, grub2

I have a laptop running Ubuntu Server. I installed Ubuntu Desktop onto it by running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. Now, by default, the computer boots into gnome. What can I do to make it boot to a command line again. I do not want to boot into gnome by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove GDM from the startup process.
Here are a couple of methods:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
sudo rcconf
```

- http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2008/07/02/enabledisable-gdm-in-ubuntu/

Or this method edits /etc/init/gdm.conf
Add 2 to the runlevel

```
stop on runlevel [0126]
```

- https://serverfault.com/questions/137776/disable-gdm-in-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: Awesome, ill give this a try

Comment: Please snip the relevant portion of the information in the answer next time. Links die and did for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the `ubuntu-desktop` package from being loaded:

##### Disable / Enable GUI on System Boot

###### Disable

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
```

###### Enable

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical
```

##### Stop / Start GUI manually

###### Stop

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3
```

###### Start

```
sudo systemctl start gdm3
```

---

###### TTY's

You can use function keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> with function keys <kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> and have four TTY sessions open if you choose.
Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will return you to the login prompt of your graphical desktop session.